# Cookies in http config retriever in vert.x

Tags: java, vert.x

I wish to use a http config retriever. The one mentioned on https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-config/java/#_http takes in just the host, port and path. I need to send cookies along with my http request. Is there a support for cookies in ConfigStoreOptions itself? Or do I have to write my custom config store, and if so, then how?

Answer (score 0):

`HttpRetriever` uses simple `HttpClient` underneath:

https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-config/blob/master/vertx-config/src/main/java/io/vertx/config/impl/spi/HttpConfigStoreFactory.java#L43

Only available options are listed here:
https://github.com/eclipse/vert.x/blob/master/src/main/java/io/vertx/core/http/HttpClientOptions.java#L246

You can create a feature request and post the link here, and I'll try to handle it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Here is the feature request: [link](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-web/issues/1007).